# Follow-up question about summary only offence

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom, england-and-wales, police, criminal-procedure

I am following on from a question that I posted [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/57431/powers-of-entry-when-it-is-summary-only-offence?rq=1).

> **Person A:** Reported suspect for one indictable offence.
>
> **Person B:** Reported suspect for several summary only offences.

I understand based on the feedback from my original question which I linked above, that the police would have power of entry into the suspect's home without a warrant because **Person A** reported the suspect for an indictable only offence.

When the suspect is being arrested for this indictable only offence, are the police allowed to then arrest the suspect for the summary only offences too whilst the police are still inside of the suspect's house, or must they wait until the suspect is taken outside (or somewhere else like a police station) before doing this?

Based on the answer to the above paragraph, if the police were meant to have arrested the person for the summary only offences outside of the suspect's home, could a suspect have those summary only offences thrown out of court?

Answer (score 3):

**When the suspect is being arrested for this indictable only offence, are the police allowed to then arrest the suspect for the summary only offences too whilst the police are still inside of the suspect's house?**

**YES**, as long as the arresting officer *suspects* an offence has been committed and *believes* the arrest is necessary for any of the reasons given in s.24 PACE [summarised here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/61658/is-mere-accusation-without-evidence-other-than-testimony-of-the-accuser-grounds/61660?r=SearchResults#61660)

**Could a suspect have those summary only offences thrown out of court?**

**NO**. There may be other reasons to offer no evidence at trial, but being arrested for a summary only offence in the circumstances described is not one of them.